# In AngularJS, the use of $ in a filter, inside a template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been reviewing the angular directives of bootstrap, [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). Specifically the typeahead directive.

In the provided example code, appears this line:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

Calls me the attention filter:$viewValue. What's the purpose of $viewValue? What's the use of the dollar symbol there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variables beginning with `$` are reserved angular variables. See https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 under "Prefix naming convention"

> As a naming convention, Angular's built-in services, Scope methods and
>   a few other Angular APIs have a $ prefix in front of the name.
>
> The $ prefix is there to namespace Angular-provided services. To
>   prevent collisions it's best to avoid naming your services and models
>   anything that begins with a $.
>
> If you inspect a Scope, you may also notice some properties that begin
>   with $$. These properties are considered private, and should not be
>   accessed or modified.

More specifically, `$viewValue` is the value entered by the user into the input field. All the documentation I could find on it is:

> `typeahead='sourceExpression'` - source for the typeahead, where
>   sourceExpression can be either an array or a promie resolving to an
>   array. A special variable `$viewValue` is available while evaluating
>   this expression

From https://gist.github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/4998969

Answer (score 1):

`$viewValue` is the raw input the user is typing into the input field. In this case it's a string because the input type is text. What's happening here in the `typeahead` attribute is your saying "show a list of states, filtered by user input (`$viewValue`), limited to 8 items". That translates to showing up to 8 items based on the user input. The `$` is just a convention in AngularJS - they use `$` for publicly available functionality and `$$` for items not intended to be a part of the public API.